# Why does it appears this error when I install SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

It appears that "Performance counter registry hive consistency has failed". What's the cause of that error? And how can I resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

[image: w]

[image]

Comment: When you click on failed, what is the message?

Comment: @Prisoner picture added

Comment: have you tried the instructions at the [link you have in the error message](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956)?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search returned this [MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/205bd261-79d2-4b16-803a-f46f092c4e51/) which also references this [Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956), which is the same that the error message provides.

It looks like you'll need to do some registry edits to Perflib.

Comment: same link provided in the error message

Comment: Well look at that... Microsoft provided a helpful link! I'll keep this around for the MSDN post that looks to add to the discussion.